# Downloading Node.js

Tags: node.js

I try to download Node.js on OSX.

My message after `node --version`:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
>     Reason: image not found

My `$PATH` is:

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin

Thanks for help.

Comment: Keep errors, file contents, and code in code blocks or quotes for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

you can install using homebrew

install homebrew using this command in your terminal

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

confirm installation

```
brew -v
```

then install node.js using

```
brew install node
```

Comment: With the code '/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"' I have the answer : '-e:222: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting $end
               .map { |d| File.join(HOMEBREW_PREFIX, d) }
                ^'

Comment: /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

got it from there website https://brew.sh/